# get Shipping Address and invoice Number from paypal ios sdk swift

Tags: ios, paypal, sdk, paypal-rest-sdk

I have problem with fetching PayPal details .
Have integrated payPal by referring https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK.
Getting

```
[("response"): {
    "create_time" = "2018-07-10T06:04:31Z";
    id = "PAY-54V16641NP848082ULNCEYTQ";
    intent = sale;
    state = approved;
}, ("response_type"): payment, ("client"): {
    environment = sandbox;
    "paypal_sdk_version" = "2.18.1";
    platform = iOS;
    "product_name" = "PayPal iOS SDK";
}]
```

and other details like

```
 intent = sale;\n        
 state = approved;\n    
 };\n    \"
 response_type\" = payment;\n}\n
 Details: (null)\n
 Shipping Address: (null)\n
 Invoice Number: (null)\n
 Custom: (null)\n
 Soft Descriptor: (null)\n
 Payee email: (null)\n
 BN code: (null)
```

are coming null.
Why null values are coming? How to fetch payee name, email and other details?
Should I send any other request to Paypal?

Comment: Shpuj , I am also facing this issue.can you help me out if you resolved

Comment: Yeah....from PayPal we will get ID and we need to pass this to backend team. They will handle this and will send back other details.